# Present parent sheet over child sheet

Tags: ios, swiftui

is it somehow possible to have a view hierarchy like this and be able to set *Support* `sheet` presentation on, with a button click from *Scanner* `sheet`?

This solution only shows the *Support* sheet when the child *Scanner* sheet is dismissed, but I need to be able to go from Support right back to Scanner sheet

```
@State var qrSheet = false
@State var help = false


var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Dashboard") {
            qrSheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $qrSheet) {
            Button("Help") {
                help.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $help) {
        Text("Support")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.sheet` modifiers should be in different (non-sequenced) view hierarchies

The required scenario can be achieved, for example, placing support

```
    .sheet(isPresented: $qrSheet) {
        Button("Help") {
            help.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $help) {     // << here !!
            Text("Support")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is unfortunately something I am trying to avoid, if its somehow even possible. 

I need to be able to handle button taps from anywhere within the app, and open one "global" sheet, which displays the required data. Think of it as a single place, that is responsible for handling all possible error massages or in this case FAQ list.

Might convince my team members, that this is actually the only "right" way. To not try to fight with SwiftUI and instead use its features as they are supposed to, if there is no other way to achieve the desired logic.